# IMCE: Prevent deletion if file is in use

Tags: 7, files

Does any one know of a way to prevent a file from being deleted through IMCE if the file is in use?  I saw this feature requested http://drupal.org/node/628246 and there is a comment to state that this feature is already in dev but I'm not finding that this is the case.

Comment: I think that this question as asked is actually a support request for the issue it points to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with IMCE but Drupal core provides a file_usage table that is for locking/unlocking files. These are the functions used to interact with it:

```
file_usage_add()
file_usage_delete()
file_usage_list()
```

Drupal's file_delete() then checks the usage table before deleting a file.

Comment: I think its not related to drupal. IMCE will manipulate files which is completely separated from drupal. it means you have not drupal's file_delete() in IMCE